# docker: Error response from daemon ... no such device

Tags: python, docker, volume

My goal is to limit the size of a Docker volume. Here is the command I use to create a Docker volume:
**

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt          device=/Users/baominh/PycharmProjects/miha_cloud/source_code/admin/volume KBndfoo4**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZPab.png)
**

```
docker run -it \
 -p 46277:3000 \
 --memory=0.5g \
 --cpus=0.1 \
 --volume=KBndfoo4:/uploads \
 baominh/uploadfile-nodejs:free-web-service
```

**

ERROR: **

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount /Users/baominh/PycharmProjects/miha_cloud/source_code/admin/volume:/var/lib/docker/volumes/KBndfoo4/_data: no such device.
See 'docker run --help'
```

.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpZb.png)
/Users/baominh/PycharmProjects/miha_cloud/source_code/admin/volume" is exist

Comment: Output docker volume ls.

Comment: You must check the EXACT name of your volume,which you will pass to run command.

Comment: Your volume name is "KBndfoo4," and when you check with "docker volume ls," I can already see it listed there.

Comment: Can you use the bind-mount syntax; `docker run -v "$PWD/source_code/admin/volume:/uploads`, without the intermediate named volume?

Comment: Yes I can, but when I use that syntax, how can I limit a size